# Changing multiple jquery mobile "data-theme" property from one place

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I am using **JQuery Mobile** to develop my mobile website. Currently, I have to set the `'data-theme'` property several times throughout my *HTML document* to be able to incorporate a particular theme. Is it possible to set the `'data-theme'` property once, maybe in a javascript function, or something to that effect? The solution would need the theme to style all my elements. I attempted to solve the issue using CSS style-sheets, but it failed to work as a solution.

My Webpage's HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0/demos/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0/demos/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="CodeGeneral.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0/demos/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleMaincss.css">

    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body onload="GenerateData();" data-role = "page" >
    <div data-role="header" class="HeaderBar">
    <img src="Logos v2/Header.png" alt="" class="HeaderImage">
    </div> 

    //Content on page

    <div data-role="footer" class="NavBar" data-position="fixed">       
    <div data-role="navbar">
           //Navigation button creation
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My javascript:

```
$(document).delegate("[data-role='page']", 'pagebeforecreate', 
    function () {
         $(this).attr('data-theme', 'a')
    }
 ); 

function GenerateData() {
    //Things carried out during loading
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from the jQuery Mobile Docs:

> The data-theme attribute can be applied to the header and footer
>   containers to apply any of the lettered theme color swatches. While
>   the data-theme attribute could be added to the content container, we
>   recommend adding it instead to div or container that has been assigned
>   the data-role="page" attribute to ensure that the background color is
>   applied to the full page. When this is done, all widgets on the page
>   will also inherit the theme specified in the page container. However,
>   headers and footers will default to theme "a". If you want to have a
>   page with, for example, only theme "b" for all its elements, including
>   its header and footer, you will need to specify data-theme="b" to the
>   page div as well as the header and footer divs.

Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/pages-themes.html

So basically if you add `data-theme="a"` to the `data-role="page"` tags then everything should inherit the `a` theme. You can test that by messing with the "theme swatch change" links at the top of the link above.

**UPDATE**

To programmatically change the theme of a page add this code to your site:

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pagecreate', function (e) {
    $(this).removeClass('ui-body-a ui-body-b ui-body-c ui-body-d ui-body-e').addClass('ui-body-a').attr('data-theme', 'a');
});
```

But this creates overhead for the user's browser while rendering the website so I suggest altering the hard-coded `data-theme` attributes on the `data-role="page"` tags.

**UPDATE**

You can also do this inside the `mobileinit` event handler by changing the `page prototype`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.theme  = "a";
});
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
```

This will make any page without a set `data-theme` attribute default to the `a` theme.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tEbD5/3/

Comment: so is there a way to call a function to change the theme of all my pages at once? It's hard to go into every pages html and change it manually

Comment: `$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pagebeforecreate', function () {$(this).attr('data-theme', 'a')});`

Comment: @theNewbProgrammer The block of code I posted should be placed in the global context to make sure it has already been parsed when the `pagebeforecreate` event fires.

Comment: @theNewbProgrammer I tested the code and it needed a tweak, here is what I found to work: `$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pagecreate', function (e) {$(this).removeClass('ui-body-a ui-body-b ui-body-c ui-body-d ui-body-e').addClass('ui-body-a').attr('data-theme', 'a');});`. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tEbD5/ (notice that I set the data-theme for the page to be `e` but then programmatically change it to `a`)

Comment: @theNewbProgrammer check-out the two **updates** in my answer. The first one has been changed so it is now different than your code. Both of these **updates** have demos to show they work.

Comment: sorry about that, i made the comment before i saw the change

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5785/discussion-between-thenewbprogrammer-and-jasper)

Comment: This works for simple cases, but from what I can tell, when you apply a data-theme, that data-theme also gets applied to nested jquery mobile widgets.  All of these nested widgets will also need to have their data-theme attribute and their classes updated.  To complicate things further, it looks like some widgets apply parent data-theme's to particular nested widgets.

Comment: @Josh You are correct, I've got another answer that does more than this, finding different types of widgets and updating their classes and data-attributes. I can't find it right now but if you care to take a look it's under my jQuery Mobile answers. Although I'm sure it won't work in all situations without expanding on the code.